# TSQL Creating a Table using another User Defined Type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, usertype

I have a stored procedure that receives a (n) list of filters stored as GUIDs. What I need is a stored procedure that will receive an (n) list of an (n) list of filters so that I can return comparisons each (n) list of filters. Is this possible, and how would you script it?

For reference, the current user type looks like the following:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[GuidList] AS TABLE(
    [Value] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Value] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

Comment: No you can't use table types as column datatypes. Why not just add an additional column to the table type that acts as a grouping identifier?

Answer (score 1):

If all you really want to do is have a list of lists (a 2-tier hierarchy, I think is what you're asking for), just use XML instead.

```
<guid_lists>
    <guid_list>
        <guid value = '' />
        <guid value = '' />
        <guid value = '' />
        <guid value = '' />
    </guid_list>
    <guid_list>
        <guid value = '' />
        <guid value = '' />
        <guid value = '' />
        <guid value = '' />
    </guid_list>
</guid_lists>
```

If that isn't usable, you may need to clarify the purpose for using a `USER TYPE`.